# sql. Getting a max(avg(column))

Tags: mysql, sql

I've simplified my problem and created this example to better illustrate.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_company` (
  `source_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `company_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `clicks` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`source_id`,`company_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My Data:

```
INSERT INTO table_company VALUES
(1,100,8),(2,100,7),(3,200,9),(4,300,3),(5,100,4),(6,400,5),(7,100,10),(8,500,4),(9,500,9),(10,400,9);


SELECT source_id,company_id,AVG(clicks) AS avg_click FROM table_company
GROUP BY source_id,company_id
ORDER BY avg_click DESC;
```

Gives me:

```
source_id  company_id  avg_click  
---------  ----------  -----------
        7         100      10.0000
        3         200       9.0000
        9         500       9.0000
       10         400       9.0000
        1         100       8.0000
        2         100       7.0000
        6         400       5.0000
        5         100       4.0000
        8         500       4.0000
        4         300       3.0000
```

I want to write a query to give me:

```
source_id  company_id  avg_click  
---------  ----------  -----------
        7         100      10.0000
        3         200       9.0000
        9         500       9.0000
       10         400       9.0000
        4         300       3.0000
```

ie. Only keep the company_id that have the MAX(avg_click)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT source_id, company_id, MAX(avg_click) as max_click FROM 
(SELECT source_id,company_id,AVG(clicks) AS avg_click FROM table_company
GROUP BY source_id,company_id
ORDER BY avg_click DESC) tmp
GROUP BY company_id
```

Comment: thanks.  I had something similar but didn't do my outer GROUP BY correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT MAx(source_id), company_id, MAX(avg_click)
 from (SELECT source_id,company_id,AVG(clicks) AS avg_click FROM #table_company 
    GROUP BY source_id,company_id 
    )as tbl
 GROUP by company_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlation:

```
SELECT source_id, company_id, avg_click
FROM table_company TC
WHERE avg_click=(SELECT max(avg_click)
             FROM table_company TC2
             WHERE TC.company_id=TC2.company_id
             GROUP BY TC2.company_id);
```

You can also use WITH clause:

```
WITH pom AS(SELECT company_id, max(avg_click) MaxAvgCl
            from table_company
            group by company_id)
SELECT pom.company_id, T.avg_click, T.source_id
FROM pom JOIN table_company T on T.company_id=pom.company_id 
                              and T.avg_click=pom.MaxAvgCl;
```