# SQL- Finding the users with the Maximum average score

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my schema:

```
create TABLE sample (
  userId      INT,
  score       INT
);

INSERT INTO sample VALUES (1,10);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (1,15);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (1,20);

INSERT INTO sample VALUES (2,100);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (2,200);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (2,500);

INSERT INTO sample VALUES (4,100);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (4,200);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (4,500);

INSERT INTO sample VALUES (3,5);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (3,5);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (3,10);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (3,7);
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (3,2);
```

I want to find the user ID's of those who have the maximum highest average score. Note there could be more than one! So for the above sample data, the answer would be: 2 and 4, becuase they both have a average score of 266.666... .

I have a working SQL for this problem:

```
select s.USERID
from sample s
group by USERID
having AVG(s.SCORE) IN (
  -- Gets the Maximum Average Score (returns only 1 result)
  select MAX(average_score) as Max_Average_Score
  from (
    -- Gets the Average Score
    select AVG(s2.SCORE) as average_score
    from sample s2
    group by USERID
  )
);
```

But I think it is a bit inefficient because I'm calculating the average score twice. Once for the main SQL and again for finding the max avg score. Is there a better way?

Note: I'm using SQL Plus

Comment: see this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557897/sql-getting-a-maxavgcolumn

Comment: Does each userId have the same number of records? If so, then you can just use SUM, rather than AVG, which might compute quicker...

Comment: No it can be different. My post will be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only say how I would solve this with DB2 SQL
I would create a temponary table where you can save the average score for each user and select the maximum value from it. This is possible in sql plus too: [How to create a temporary table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671518/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-oracle).

Here is the solution in DB2 Syntax (not tested)

http://www.cs.newpaltz.edu/~pletcha/DB/db2_TempTables.html

```
WITH tempTable 
AS (select userid, AVG(score) FROM sample GROUP BY userid)

SELECT * FROM tempTable WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM tempTable)
```

Comment: That's not a "temp table", it's a "common table expression" (but would work for Oracle just as well)

Comment: I found this link helpful in regards to temp tables: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_rewrite_temporary_tables.htm in Oracle

Answer (score 4):

```
select userid from
(select userid, rank() over (order by avg(score) desc) rw
from sample group by userid)
where rw = 1;
```

Calculate avg score for each user, than calculate the rank of each score using analytic functions (which are performed after the grouping). Lastly get the rows with the first rank

Answer (score 0):

Listo, changed to Oracle:

```
select userId, AVG(score) AS promedio 
from [sample] 
where rownum = 1
group by userId
order by AVG(score) desc
```

Comment: This is not Oracle syntax.

Comment: and some of it is not in english

Comment: `[sample]` is an invalid SQL identifier.

Comment: Also I want ALL users with the highest average score, NOT just 1. Also i'm not sure what [sample] means. is this the same as sample.